# Edit image in Android

Tags: android, image, camera

I'm want to do something like whatsapp, when user capture an image or select an image from gallery, they can edit the image/ draw something on the image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use this [library](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many libraries for that.

Just try this [Whatsapp like photo editor](https://github.com/DroidNinja/Whatsapp-Like-PhotoEditor)

Checkout the sample and library

```
ImageEditor.Builder(this, imagePath)
                .setStickerAssets("stickers")
                .disable(ImageEditor.EDITOR_TEXT) //to disable something
                .open()
```

You will get the result in onActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
      ImageEditor.RC_IMAGE_EDITOR ->
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
          val imagePath: String = data.getStringExtra(ImageEditor.EXTRA_EDITED_PATH)
          edited_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath))
        }
    }
  }
```